# Cannot pass blade variable in onChange function in select

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a select option as below.

```
 @foreach($destinations as $destination)
{!! Form::select('destination', $counts, $destination->ordering, array('onchange'=>'fetch_select(this.value,$destination->id)') !!}
@endforeach
```

I am trying to pass a variable called $destination->id in onchange function as above which will trigger a function in java-script later on. However, I am not able to pass this variable like i have done above. Throws a lot of errors. It says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

in the inspect console.

I tried with:

```
 'onchange'=>'fetch_select(this.value,destination->id)'
'onchange'=>'fetch_select(this.value,"$destination->id")'
'onchange'=>'fetch_select(this.value,(destination->id))'
'onchange'=>'fetch_select(this.value,($destination->id))'
```

None of them works .. How can i get around this. With Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is treating *destination->id* as a literal because of the single quotes. You're actually getting the value *destination->id* passed as a parameter to the function, and *destination->id* is not legal javascript. It's reading it as *destination minus greater than id*, which makes no sense.

Try

```
'fetch_select(this.value,' . $destination->id . ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Form select function is not closed, missing ) , try below code to avoid syntax error

```
{!! Form::select('destination', $counts, $destination->ordering, array('onchange'=>"fetch_select(this.value,$destination->id)")) !!}
```